# how to make div take full width of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

How do I get the color div to take up the full width of the parent div `.starter` so that the entire width is one color? I've tried everything and haven't made progress. I've isolated the problem for ease of containment. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>Pricing</title>
        <link href="styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        </div>
            <ul id="plans">
                <li>
                    <div id='starter' class="col-4 col-m-12">
                        <h1>Starter</h1>
                        <div class="color"><h3 id="test">1 Hour</h3></div>
                        <p>$25</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
} 
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
#header{
    padding:15px;
    background-color:rgb(157,221,220);
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

body{
    background-color:white;
    color:rgb(164,111,67);}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(164,111,67);
}
#info{
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}
#pricing{

    padding:30px;
}
#starter, #basic, #deluxe{
    background-color:lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    border:5px solid white;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
}
#test{
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
}

#color{
    margin:0;
    background-color:white;
}
html, body{}
```

I want it to look like this[image]

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle of this? Would be easier to see what you have. Also in your css you have #color{...} but color is a class not id, so it should be .color{...}

Comment: U need to remove the padding on [class*="col-"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting messed up by the padding on the parent. Change it to:

```
[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;;
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;

}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
} 
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
#header{
    padding:15px;
    background-color:rgb(157,221,220);
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

body{
    background-color:white;
    color:rgb(164,111,67);}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(164,111,67);
}
#info{
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}
#pricing{

    padding:30px;
}
#starter, #basic, #deluxe{
    background-color:lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    border:5px solid white;
}
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li{
    list-style:none;
}
#test{
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
}

#color{
    margin:0;
    background-color:white;
}
html, body{}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>      
        <title>Pricing</title>
        <link href="styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        </div>
            <ul id="plans">
                <li>
                    <div id='starter' class="col-4 col-m-12">
                        <h1>Starter</h1>
                        <div class="color"><h3 id="test">1 Hour</h3></div>
                        <p>$25</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me because the parent div css code that applies to all divs was adding 15 extra p x. Answers appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can an extra CSS property to the parent div:

```
#starter.col-4.col-m-12 {
  padding:0px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arp5cod2/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the child `div` is a child of the parent `div`, then you can set its width to 100%, which will set it to 100% of the parent width. If you know the width of the parent, then you can just set its width to the same value.

```css
#parent {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: gray;
}
#child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add an id to the div that is containing the "1 hour" and add margins to that

```
   margin-right:25px;
   margin-left:25px;
```

check it out: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbRoXK

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
#starter {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNjwYB